How do I make the number stay the same, but continue from where it was left off if the day is different
I'm trying to make a LOT number generator. If a supplier is mentioned in column K in the same month, it grows, it has a value, but I don't know how to make it stay the same if it is in the same day. So if supplier C supplies me on month:6 day:17 year: 24 (6/17/24), the ending value should be 001, if we have one more month:6 day:17 year: 24 value should be 001 again. But when it is month:6 day:18 year: 24, the value should be 002. I have already fixed how value is different for each supplier, and values reset in each month. But I don't know how to keep the value same if supplier supplied us that day.
I have tried If but couldn't make it work
Current formula:
=TEXT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("K$1:K"&ROW()), K2, INDIRECT("F$1:F"&ROW()), F2, INDIRECT("H$1:H"&ROW()), H2), "000")


You can nest a countifs to check if the combo of the date & supplier is 1 or greater and if so, lookup the original key for that day/supplier

Hi Mark, I couldn't do it. İs it something like
==IF(COUNTIFS(K:K, K2, F:F, F2, H:H, H2) > 1, INDEX(K:K, MATCH(1, (K:K=K2)(F:F=F2)(H:H=H2), 0)), TEXT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("K$1:K"&ROW()), K2, INDIRECT("F$1:F"&ROW()), F2, INDIRECT("H$1:H"&ROW()), H2), "000"))

[Edit] your current formula into your question. Add in some sample data in text form using a Table Markdown generator.

I would approach this as counting the cells above the row you're working in to check if the date & Supplier combination exists. If it does then use the match to get the code. If there's no match on the date, then we check if there's a match on the month. If there is a match there, but no exact date, we do a lookup to find the LAST match for the month and add 1 to it to get the next code. Lastly, if there's no matching date or matching month, it would reset to 1, so we set it to 1.
My formula is: =TEXT( IF( COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A2,$B$1:B1,B2)>=1, XLOOKUP(A2&B2,$A$1:A1&$B$1:B1,$D$1:D1,0,0), IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A2,$C$1:C1,C2)>=1, XLOOKUP(A2&C2,$A$1:A1&$C$1:C1,$D$1:D1,0,0,-1)+1,1)),"000")


If I understood well you could also try this:
=LET(s,[SUPPLIER CODE],      c,[SAMPLE CODE],     m,TEXT([SAMPLE DATE],"mmyy"),     d,DAY([SAMPLE DATE]),
     sc,[@[SUPPLIER CODE]], cc,[@[SAMPLE CODE]], mc,TEXT([@[SAMPLE DATE]],"mmyy"), dc,DAY([@[SAMPLE DATE]]),
     f,LAMBDA(x,FILTER(x,(m=mc)*(ROW(c)<=ROW(cc)))),
"D"&cc&mc&"/"&TEXT(SUM(N(f(d)&f(c)&f(m)&f(s)=dc&cc&mc&sc)),"000")&"-"&sc)

Where I made use of the Table references using LET to keep it more compact.
Inside LET I first declare:

s the Supplier code column
c the Sample code column
`m the month/year notation of the Sample date column
d the day of the month of the Sample date column

Next the same letters are used with addition c to it to declared the current row of the same as above.
f is used as a function and filters the argumented range/array for each row where the Sample date text representation as mmyy equals the same of current row and the row is smaller or equal to current row.
example of the function: f(d) in row 5 of example below would return row 4 and 5 of d. Summing the quantity equaling the current row's value of d: (dc) results in 2.
Next we concatenate the required values + counter.

PS in your image I noted that you're not using the table as intended. the table should end at the last row containing data. If you type new data below the table would expand automatically (including this formula).

Thanks for the solution, I didn't know '=LET' existed before. I originally used
=CONCAT("D", B2, F2,  H2,"/",L2,"-", K2) for the LOT number.  Thanks for the information about the table as well :)
